# Extract phone number using regex with different formats python

Tags: python, regex

Hi I have a string of texts which include a phone number in many different formats, I need to be able to extract just the phone number.

Eg: "Hi my name is marc and my phone number is 03-123456 and i would like 2 bottles of water 0.5L"

possible phone formats:

- All phone numbers begin with area code either 03 or 70 or 71 or 76 (no other option)
- all phone numbers are 6 digits after the area code
- Different msgs have different formats such as 03-123456 or 03123456 or 03 123 456 or 03 123456 or 03/123456 (you get the idea)

I am able to find the index using find function in python by looking for (03 or 70 or 76 or 71) but I am not able to find the index of the last number.

```
number_start = message.find('03' or '70' or '76' or '71')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
\b(?:03|7[016])[- /]?\d{3} ?\d{3}\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?:03|7[016])` Match one of `03` `70` `71` `76`
- `[- /]?` Optionally match `-` a space or `/`
- `\d{3} ?\d{3}` Match 6 digits with an optional space after the 3rd digits
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pnbvFL/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wfeeRI)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\b(?:03|7[016])[- /]?\d{3} ?\d{3}\b"
test_str = "Hi my name is marc and my phone number is 03-123456 and i would like 2 bottles of water 0.5L"
matches = re.search(regex, test_str)

if matches:
    print(matches.group())
```

Output

```
03-123456
```

Comment: Im new to regex and not sure about the code I should use? Is it re.search(pattern,string)?

Comment: @MarcHenrySaad If you want to find all of them, you could also use re.findall. See https://ideone.com/DX5vbr If you want to find the first location, you can use re.search.

Comment: Some texts show as:

"Hi my name is marc
03-123456"

Because of the line break the regex is not detecting the number. Even though i read that regex automatically accounts for line breaks. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MarcHenrySaad Which linebreak do you mean? https://regex101.com/r/l9jKsF/1

Comment: There is a line break between a certain text and a phone number. So it seems as the script is only checking the first line

Comment: @MarcHenrySaad That is due to the nature of [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), it `Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match` In that case you can use the re.findall example that I commented previously https://ideone.com/DX5vbr